# How would I use regular expressions to remove a parenthesised substring?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression (regex) question...

How would I use regular expressions to remove the contents in parenthesis in a string in C# like this:

"SOMETHING (#2)"

The part of the string I want to remove always appears within paranthesis and they are always # followed by some number.  The rest of the string needs to be left alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove everything including the parenthesis

```
var input = "SOMETHING (#2) ELSE";
var pattern = @"\(#\d+\)";
var replacement = "";

var replacedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```

Remove only contents within parenthesis

```
var input = "SOMETHING (#2) ELSE";
var pattern = @"(.+?)\(#\d+\)(.+?)";
var replacement = "$1()$2";

var replacedString = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replacement);
```